# What is the best way to move an online Azure Function to a local git repository?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-functions-core-tools

I have written an Azure Function App by using the User Interface of Azure Portal. The code is written in C#.

Now, I want to:

1. download all of the relevant code and configuration files of this
   function app
2. Create an IDE project (e.g. IntelliJ, Visual Studio Code, ...)
3. store it in a git repository
4. Deploy the code from IDE or command line to Azure and thereby replacing the previously written Azure function.

So far, I have found only documentation on how to initiate Azure function projects with no previous code. Does somebody know how to do above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could go to your function **Overview** page, click on Download app content as shown below.

[image]

And in your situation, you want configuration files, so select the **Content and Visual Studio Project** and **Include app settings in the download**. **What is app settings?** This will include a `local.settings.json` file which contains your application settings.

[image]

Also the third party .dlls are included.

[image]

In the VS, select the folder and it will be working.

[image]

**Update:**

Open the function with vs, then just right click the function and choose Publish, it will show you the publish page. Click start, then you will be able to publish it to a existing Function.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thx for the quick response. The download I was trying out already. However, I see no option then to publish the app into Azure again from my local environment. How did you configure at your end?

Comment: @Bertolt, I have updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: Ok, thx. Publish did not work for me in my local environment. Will try again and debug.

Comment: @Bertolt, could you share me your picture? What's your runtime, .net or others?

Comment: We use dotnet as environment. Currently we are adding unit testing to our functions and then will re-try uploading to Azure. I will mark the answer as soon as we're done. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [Setting up a CI/CD pipeline for Azure Functions](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/) doc which explain each step in detail.